# C: Specifying a variable number of decimal points for output of float in printf?

Tags: c

I'm just getting to grips with C. I'm trying to print a floating point number, which I am aware I can do as follows...

```
printf("Rate: %f.\n",rate);
```

But I want to print only a specific number of decimal points, specified by a variable "decimalPoints". The decimalPoints value is determined by reading a string and converting it to a float using sscanf. Thus it is not limited to a specific value so %.2f won't work for instance. But say the value of decimalPoints is 2, is there a way to go about doing this?

i.e. something of the following format?

```
int decimalPoints = 2;
printf("Rate: %{decimalPoints}f.\n",rate);
```

Comment: The title implies that your program crashes on using `sscanf` but the post has nothing to do with crash and asks something else.

Comment: A good [`printf` and family reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf) might come in handy.

Comment: `printf("Rate: %{decimalPoints}f.\n",rate);`  It will give output as `{decimalPoints}f.`

Comment: If more programmers read the documentation, they wouldn't have to guess as much at what the syntax might be. ;)

Comment: Sorry guys, I didn't mean to post that title, it was the start of a title of a previous question I managed to resolve myself before posting.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't specify how many floating point decimal places you want to print like this.

Instead of

```
printf("Rate: %{decimalPoints}f.\n",rate);
```

do

```
printf("Rate: %.*f\n", decimalPoints, rate);
```

`%.*f` used in printf will take the first integer argument after the string as number of decimals you want to print with your floating point number.

Some testing:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    float rate = 1.223321f;
    int decimalPoints;
    for (decimalPoints = 0; decimalPoints < 6; decimalPoints++)
    {
        printf("Rate: %.*f \n", decimalPoints, rate);
    }
}
```

Output:

> Rate: 1
>
> Rate: 1.2
>
> Rate: 1.22
>
> Rate: 1.223
>
> Rate: 1.2233
>
> Rate: 1.22332